# Omitting elementwrappers and getting the xml root value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

```
<root xmlns:test="url" test:attr1="10" test:attr2="someValue>
    <elementwrapper>
        <secondElementwrapper>
            <element>someValue</element>
            <differentelement>anotherValue</differentelement>
        </secondElementwrapper>
    </elementwrapper>
</root>
```

The following classes are made:

```
public class XmlEntities
    {
        [XmlRoot("root")]

        public class Root
            {
                [XmlElement("elementwrapper")]
                public Elementwrapper Elementwrapper{ get; set; }
            }

        public class Elementwrapper
            {
                [XmlElement("secondElementwrapper")]
                public SecondElementwrapper SecondElementwrapper{ get; set; }
            }

        public class Values
            {
                [XmlElement("element")]
                public string Element{ get; set; }

                [XmlElement("differentelement")]
                public string Differentelement{ get; set; }
            }
    }
```

And here is where i serialize and deserialize the xml:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
var xmlRecord = new XmlEntities.Root();

try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlEntities.Root));
        xmlRecord = (XmlEntities.Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        reader.Close();
    }
catch (Exception e) { }
```

- I want to access xmlRecord.Element instead of xmlRecord.Elementwrapper.Values.Element
- How do i get the test:attr1 value?*

If i remove the class Elementwrapper and Root, xmlRecord returns null.
[XmlAttribute] inside the Root class to get attr1 value doesnt work for me.

Thank you!

EDIT:
The element was a copy/paste wrong doing. Fixed that. I also added :test infront of the attr1, forgot that.

EDIT:
Adding the following as sgk mentioned, inside the root class, allowed me to access the attribute

```
[XmlAttribute("attr1", Namespace = "url")]
public string attr { get; set; }
```

EDIT: And is there a way to map the classes differently? So i can access xmlRecord.Element directly?

EDIT: @TonyStark seems like what i want needs to be approached a different way, but then again this already works i just need to access the element trough the nodes (xmlRecord.elementwrapper.secondelementwrapper.element) for those that are wondering.

To access the attribute of root i simply use : xmlRecord.attr after i added the xmlattribute that its written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I want to access `xmlRecord.Element` instead of `xmlRecord.Elementwrapper.Values.Element` - Based on the XML structure you have, to `Deserialize` and access the `<element>` value and `<differentelement>` value -  you need to go through root-->elementwrapper-->secondElementwrapper.
2. How do i get the attr1 value? - add `[XmlAttribute("attr1")]` inside class Root

Then, `[XmlElement("<elementwrapper>")]` should be `[XmlElement("elementwrapper")]` otherwise when you `Deserialize` you will always get null as there is no matching element.

See below

```
public class XmlEntities
{
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("elementwrapper")]
        public Elementwrapper Elementwrapper { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("attr1", Namespace="url")]
        public string attr1;
    }

    public class Elementwrapper
    {
        [XmlElement("secondElementwrapper")]
        public SecondElementwrapper SecondElementwrapper { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondElementwrapper
    {
        [XmlElement("element")]
        public string Element { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("differentelement")]
        public string Differentelement { get; set; }
    }        
}
```

Comment: The element was a copy/paste wrong doing. Fixed that.
I also added :test infront of the attr1 and 2, forgot that.
And is there another way to access xmlRecord directly the values? Is there a way to map it differently?

Comment: Updated answer to use namespace

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way to access the values directly unless you read the specific section of the XML and then deserialize that bit. I believe this approach will not work for you as you are also looking for attribute values from the root element.